# How to redirect page in Wordpress by coding

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress twentysixteen theme. There I have created a page template. In that I have created a login form. I want to redirect a user to the next page after successful login.

I tried:

```
header('Location: http://website.com/my-page/');
wp_redirect(get_page_by_title('My Page'));
```

saying error

> headers already sent

Comment: Refer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/  or http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/

Comment: try to call ob_get_clean before wp_redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workarond this problem by redirecting page via javascript

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/my-page/"</script>';
exit;
```

Comment: Yeah it's working now.. Thanks.. Do we need to Exit; as well? without exit also working. Thank you everyone for help..

Answer (score 0):

Page templates are not appropriate for writing redirects. Try to put your redirect logic in functions.php with an appropriate hook.

```
// Add the code in functions.php 

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpso39502735_redirect', 10, 3 );

function wpso39502735_redirect() {

    // Add your logic here otherwise all requests will redirect to "My Page"
    return get_page_by_title('My Page');
}
```

If by any chance you must redirect after the page load, use Javascript instead.

Comment: Did you replace `'your-template-name'` with your actual template name? Otherwise please share the code you have written and errors if any

Comment: yes I replaced it with my template name. No error, just running as it was before. can't redirect

Comment: You need to add this code in functions.php file not in page template.

Comment: I missed the login part somehow. I have updated the code and changed the required hook. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not redirecting :(

Comment: Updated the code one more time. Please try this one, I am running out of options after this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that file has UTF-8 without BOM encoding and you dont print enything to browser.